# HTML/CSS - How do I make divs to size according to their contents?

Tags: css, html, autosize

I have 2 divs side by side.

In the first div, I have 2 labels side by side, and one input text below them. One of the labels is an error information. Sometimes it will be displayed, sometimes not. When it's not display, I'd like the div to resize to be smaller, so the second div can be closer to it.

The second thing is the same thing, except it has one label div, therefore it doesn't requires a resize.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? There is an awesomely drawn example of what I want to acahieve below:

[image: Awesomely Drawn Example Of Autosize Width]

This is the code.

```
<div id="main-div">
<div id="address-number-div">
    <label>Number</label>
    <label class="error" id="number-error">Empty Field</label>
    <input id="number-input" onfocus="onfocus('number-error')"/>
</div> 

<div id="address-complement-div">
    <label>Complement</label>
    <input id="complement-input" />
</div>
```

​

and CSS:

```
div {border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 5px;}

.error{color:#FF0000; margin-left:5px;}

#main-div div {display:inline-block;}

#main-div input {display:block;}

#number-input {
    width: 16%;
}​
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Have you even tried something?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov yes please look my code. Try it in jsfiddle, it shows the same as the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyzkV/11/).

Floating your divs left should solve this problem.

Comment: This can't be achievable using inline-block? Because I have other components below these ones, and if I use float they get out of position.

Comment: You could add a wrapping div. Here's an updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zyzkV/33/) of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using a wrapper, I think the issue may be with the other html elements.

Answer (score 2):

Set them to `display: inline-block;` to let them shrink to fit the the content.

Comment: Please note that setting "display: inline-block;" on a block element will not work out of the box on IE7 - http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html

Comment: Of course I add `*display: inline; *zoom: 1;` to have an inline-block element in IE 7.

Comment: Sure thing, just wanted to point it out to the OP if they decided to use this approach. Cheers!

Comment: I'm already using `display: inline-block;` to set them side by side but they won't resize. I'm using javascript to hide the error label using `style.display = "none"` and `style.visibility = "hidden"`. To display it back I'm using `style.display = "inline"` and `style.visibility = "visible"`

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the visibility attribute, display:none should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give `width` [`<persentage>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/percentage) type value, give [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length):

```
#number-input { width: 24px; }​
```

See it with your code on [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNs7P/).

Comment: I  don't know why but in my code even though it renders the display as none and visibility as hidden it still takes up space.

Comment: Have you changed `width` to `px`?

Comment: Yes, I've changed. When I see the html output in Chrome and Firefox the label is still there occupying space, and the rendered tag has `style="display: none; visibility: hidden";`

Comment: Turns out I was using !important tag in css. Removed and now it is working.

Comment: That's good. Now you can accept the answer you will find the best.